# Display the lastest entry from Detail Table- using Linq to entities

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid as Master Table and a Pie-Chart for Detail's display. 
I have a list of Servers with their ServerID's in the Master Table like this-

[image]

and my Details table is

[image]

I would like to display the latest value of RAM(depending on the RAM_ID)- Used & Available in the Pie chart when I click on the respective serverID.

for example
the values for server 1 will be displayed as (from Ram_ID) 
[image]

for server 2

[image]

& for server 3

[image]

What I have Tried,

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        using (DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities())
        {

          var ramRow = db.UsageRAMs.OrderByDescending(c => c.ID).First();                

          var Ram = new List<UsageRAM>() { new UsageRAM() { name = "Used"  , value = ramRow.Used },
                                          new UsageRAM() { name = "Available" , value = ramRow.Available}};

          this.ramViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("ramView");
          ramViewSource.Source = Ram;
        }
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
```

XAML

```
<customControls:LabeledPieChart x:Name="labeledPieChartRAM" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="2,10,35,27" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1">
       <customControls:LabeledPieChart.LegendStyle>
       <Style TargetType="dv:Legend">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
       </Style>
     </customControls:LabeledPieChart.LegendStyle>
    <customControls:LabeledPieChart.Series>
   <customControls:LabeledPieSeries x:Name="labeledPieSeriesRAM" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ramView}}"                                                              
      PieChartLabelStyle="{StaticResource pieChartLabelStyle}" 
      PieChartLabelItemTemplate="{StaticResource pieChartLabelDataTemplate}" 
      IndependentValuePath="name" DependentValuePath="value" IsSelectionEnabled="True"
      LabelDisplayMode="ArcMidpoint" />
     </customControls:LabeledPieChart.Series>
    </customControls:LabeledPieChart>
```

output

[image]

The output for the above code displays the latest value from the details table, i.e it takes the values from RAM_ID 8, but I need values for each server when selected. how to achieve this ? kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something Like this

```
    //In this query i am grouping the record by ServerID and Selecting ServerID+ Max(Ram_ID )

     using (DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities())
     {
        var lstRamList = (from usgRam in DB.UsageRAMs 
           group usgRam  by new { usgRam.ServerID} 
           into grp
           select
           new
           {
           TMP_ID_ServerID = grp.Key.ServerID,
           TMP_MAX_RAM_ID= grp.Max(x => x.Ram_ID)}); 


 //in this lower list we save all the record from the Db.UsageRAMs where k.ServerID(from above list) == d.ServerID(from Your DB Context) && k.TMP_MAX_RAM_ID == d.Ram_ID
    var lstRAMListFinal = from d in db.UsageRAMs
    where lstRamList.Any(k =>
                        k.TMP_ID_ServerID== d.ServerID  &&
                        k.TMP_MAX_RAM_ID == d.Ram_ID)
   select d;
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the update. but I get many errors when I try this sample. did you try this ?

Comment: i dnt have the exact table and their column name so i didnt tried it. i made the query from the mentioned Tables and their column names..

Comment: Yes, i will share it.. I have edited few spacing errors and now it looks fine. could you please give me some explanation about the above code by putting them in comments. so that I can try to understand

Comment: thanks for the comment kind of you. I have edited the above update and posted a link

Comment: I still have an error :( at one place.. then if I execute only I can see. but till now thank u very much

Comment: The name 'usgRam' does not exist in the current context - I have this only error

Comment: make sure u r not missing Using Scope using (DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities()){The Above Code should be here}, If you are not missing it make sure from the Model Browser that the Table UsageRAMs exiests.... if it is not exiesting kindly update ur model from Database....

Comment: yes, all the above conditions are met in my porgram, but still I have this error. and what does mpRecords mean ?

Comment: ok i found the error i m editing just see after edition... and sorry for that cause i didn't ran the code....

Comment: It looks good now, I am going to execute, thanks a lot Salman Khan.. u saved like a bollywood star.. ^^

Comment: I have one last question, sorry for troubling you.. my pie is not displaying, what is wrong here ? i have edited the answer above.

Comment: i have not worked on this control,,, but to make sure that data is correct you can check the list (lstRAMListFinal)...

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you can simply use RECORD_DATE Column in Details table!!![image]

Comment: I already have one.. I want to display depending upon the RAM_ID column (this is a auto increment coulmn)

Comment: Then group the Detail Table by ServerID and select the Record by Max Ram_ID